# Inner Join Mysql duplicate records

Tags: mysql

I have following table in my database. I am trying to retrieve data from all three tables.

Table Structure:

```
User_New
  User_ID
  Name
  Password
  Email

User_Group_New
  User_ID
  Group_ID

Group_New
  Group_ID
  Group_Name
```

Issue: I am getting Duplicate records.

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `User_New` 
INNER JOIN User_Group_New ON User_Group_New.User_ID = User_New.User_ID
INNER JOIN Group_New ON Group_New.Group_ID = User_Group_New.Group_ID
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: Add sample input data and the result you're getting. There should not be duplicated results in the query you provided if the user_id and group_id are really PKs and you have a compound PK in user_group_new

Comment: Do you mean seeing user more than once in result? Would expect user more than once if belongs to more than one group.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM `User_New` 
INNER JOIN User_Group_New ON User_Group_New.User_ID = User_New.User_ID
INNER JOIN Group_New ON Group_New.Group_ID = User_Group_New.Group_ID
LIMIT 0, 30
```

May that solve yours.

Comment: If the IDs are PKs and there is a compound PK in user_group_new this will provide exactly the same results

Comment: @MostyMostacho OP didn't clarify well. So each solution has a success chance.

Comment: Hi all, Thanks you all for your suggestions. The idea is to create user management system. e.g. a user can be assigned to a multiple group and a group can have multiple users. User can also be an administrator or manager. Do you guys have any idea how I should structure my database?